# Mapping JSON to SQL columns using Spring Boot and Java

Tags: java, mysql

We have a JSON structure as below:

```javascript
{
    "basecurrency": "USD",
    "data_date": "2022-07-25",
    "data": {
        "AED": 3.671159,
        "AFN": 89.81064,
        "ALL": 114.523046,
        "AMD": 409.987398,
        "ANG": 1.799784,
        "100 more values",
    }
}
```

We want to push to a MySQL table structure as below:

```
create table tblData(
   ID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   base_currency varchar(10) NOT NULL,
   data_date DATE NOT NULL,
   AED REAL(16,10) NOT NULL,
   AFN REAL(16,10) NOT NULL,
   AGN REAL(16,10) NOT NULL,
   100 MORE COLUMNS,
   PRIMARY KEY (ID)
);
```

How can we map this JSON in Java and Spring Boot and push it to MySQL? Do we have to create a [POJO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_old_Java_object) of 100 or more fields and is there a better way to do it?

Comment: You can probably do fairly easily with parsing JSON to a map and using `PreparedStatement` to create the insert SQL

Comment: That would be better off as a properly relational structure.

Comment: Is the table not missing `basecurrency` column?

Comment: Yes @XtremeBaumer It was missing, i updated it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this solution to handle ordering pretty well. Also, if more columns are added to the JSON, it should handle them dynamically as well.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
        throws FileNotFoundException, IOException, SQLException, ParseException {
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    String s = "{\n" + "    \"basecurrency\": \"USD\",\n"
            + "    \"data_date\": \"2022-07-25\",\n" + "    \"data\": {\n"
            + "        \"AED\": 3.671159,\n" + "        \"AFN\": 89.81064,\n"
            + "        \"ALL\": 114.523046,\n" + "        \"AMD\": 409.987398,\n"
            + "        \"ANG\": 1.799784\n" + " }\n" + "}";
    HashMap<String, Object> readValue = new ObjectMapper().readValue(s, HashMap.class);
    System.out.println(readValue);

    List<Entry<String, Double>> data = ((Map<String, Double>) readValue.get("data"))
            .entrySet().stream().sorted((e1, e2) -> e1.getKey().compareTo(e2.getKey()))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    StringBuilder sql = new StringBuilder();
    sql.append("insert into tblData (");
    sql.append("basecurrency, ");
    sql.append("data_date ");
    for (Entry<String, Double> e : data) {
        sql.append(",");
        sql.append(e.getKey());
    }
    sql.append(")  values( ");
    sql.append("?, "); // basecurrency
    sql.append("? "); // data_date
    for (Entry<String, Double> e : data) {
        sql.append(",");
        sql.append("?");
    }
    sql.append(")");
    try (PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(s)) {
        int param = 0;
        ps.setString(param++, (String) readValue.get("basecurrency"));
        ps.setDate(param++, new java.sql.Date(sdf.parse((String) readValue.get("data_date")).getTime()));
        for (Entry<String, Double> e : data) {
            ps.setDouble(param++, e.getValue());
        }
        ps.executeUpdate();
    }
}
```

As a side note, I would advise you to change the database table to something like this:

```
create table tblData(
   ID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   data_date DATE NOT NULL,
   source_currency varchar(3),
   target_currency varchar(3),
   rate REAL(16,10) NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (ID)
);
```

That is a fairly easy POJO which you can map with [Hibernate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hibernate_%28Java%29). Then you create one entry per entry in JSON data list. This also has the advantage that you don't have to change the database if you want to support another currency.

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1**: create a wrapper class which defines `data` as a `Map<String, Double>`:

```java
public class DataWrapper {
    @JsonProperty("data")
    private Map<String, Double> data;
    
    public DataWrapper() {}
}
```

**Step 2**, read your JSON into it, e.g., via [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson) (I've used a limited example here, for brevity):

```java
DataWrapper dataWrapper = objectMapper.readValue("{\"data\": {\"AED\": 3.671159, \"AFN\": 89.81064}}", DataWrapper.class);
```

**Step 3**, generate some SQL:

```java
String tableName = "tblData";
String columnNames = String.join(", ", dataWrapper.data.keySet());
String placeholders = dataWrapper.data.keySet().stream().map(key -> ":" + key).collect(Collectors.joining(", "));

String sql = "INSERT INTO %s (%s) VALUES (%s);".formatted(tableName, columnNames, placeholders);
```

**Step 4**, pass it to the `JdbcTemplate` (you've tagged the question as Spring Boot, so I'm assuming this is OK):

```java
jdbcTemplate.update(sql, dataWrapper.data());
```

This strategy removes the need for a POJO with 100+ fields.

Comment: Does this not omit `basecurrency` and `data_date`?

Comment: @XtremeBaumer It does, yeah - I figured I'd omit them to make the solution more focused, as it seems OP already knows how to do the simple mappings :) if you think this'd be useful, please feel free to edit my answer!